# How to get var/lib/rpm/packages in Java

Tags: java, docker, berkeley-db, dnf, centos8

I'm using Java Oracle NoSQL Database Server - com.sleepycat.je

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sleepycat</groupId>
        <artifactId>je</artifactId>
        <version>18.3.12</version>
 </dependency>
```

And I try to get Berkely DB content - RPM Packages DB in Centos8 docker image

```
import com.sleepycat.je.DatabaseException;
import com.sleepycat.je.Environment;
import com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentConfig;

import java.io.File;

public class TempMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Environment myDbEnvironment = null;

    try {
        // Open the environment, creating one if it does not exist
        EnvironmentConfig envConfig = new EnvironmentConfig();
        envConfig.setAllowCreate(true);
        myDbEnvironment = new Environment(new File("C:\\Centos8\\LayerId\\var\\lib\\rpm\\Packages"),
                envConfig);

    } catch (DatabaseException dbe) {
        //  Exception handling
    }
}
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Properties.java:574)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:391)
at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.DbConfigManager.applyFileConfig(DbConfigManager.java:449)
at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.setupHandleConfig(Environment.java:313)
at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:250)
at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:228)
```

Comment: `C:\\Centos8` is valid path for CentOS?

Comment: I saved docker image on my local machine and extracted it, Then tried to run this code on var/lib/rpm/Packages file exist in the first layer in centos8

Comment: But where are you running the Java executable? Inside the Docker or in Windows?

Comment: Is `Packages` an actual Berkeley DB database file, or just a directory containing RPM packages?

Comment: I saved Centos:8 docker image to my local computer windows and extracted it. 
I found "Packages" file in "var/lib/rpm/" path  inside the first layer folder. Im trying to get its content using Java as above.

Comment: 1. Your question is wrongly tagged. It is unrelated to centos, dnf and rpm. It should be tagged *Windows*. 
2. Why do you want to access such file this way?

Comment: 1. Its not wrongly tagged. Its about Centos 8 docker image and new package manager DNF 2. I need to know installed packages in Centos 8 without running centos8 as a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

your problem for sure related to the Path I would recommend

1.replace \\ with `File.pathSeparator`

2.In debugging check that the file is existed before using it

Comment: I saved Centos:8 docker image to my local computer windows and extracted it. 
I found "Packages" file in "var/lib/rpm/" path  inside the first layer folder. Im trying to get its content using Java as above.
 So the file exist and file separator isn't the issue

Comment: I understand that .could you try to use `Files.exists ` to see if your class reach the files?